# SIM908 GPS STATUS "Location Unknown" Error

Tags: avr, c, gps, sim900, at-commands

I'm using a SIM908 module on a custom board and am having trouble getting the GPS location from it. Everything else works on the module. I can send SMS, make calls and send and receive data from a webpage. But GPS doesn't seem to work. I am using the antenna pad directly on the chip with a passive antenna.

When I call `AT+GPSSTATUS?` I receive `Location Unknown` no matter what I do. I tested this outdoors with clear view to the sky. I expected it would at least give `Location Not Fix` but `Location Unknown` seems to indicate GPS is not on, even though I call `AT+CGPSPWR=1` and `AT+CGPSRST=0` and get "OK" back almost every time. A few times, it has returned `ERROR GPS READY`, which I can't find anywhere in the datasheets, but I assume is due to not having reset the SIM908 while testing new code.

I have posted my test code below. Am I missing something?

```
// DDDR initializations (not included)
// UART Initialization
uart0_init(UART_BAUD_SELECT(UART_BAUDRATE, F_CPU));
sei();
_delay_ms(500);
// GSM Power on
PORTD |= (1<<PORTD3);
_delay_ms(1100);
PORTD &= ~(1<<PORTD3);
_delay_ms(2300);
UWriteString("AT");
// Returns: "AT" and "OK"
// So far all good
_delay_ms(1000);
// GPS Power on
UWriteString("AT+CGPSPWR=1\r");
// Returns "OK"
_delay_ms(10000);
UWriteString("AT+CGPSRST=0\r");  // Have tried with =1 with no luck
// Returns "OK"
_delay_ms(10000);
// VERY LONG DELAY
_delay_ms(30000);
_delay_ms(30000);
_delay_ms(30000);
_delay_ms(30000);
_delay_ms(30000);
_delay_ms(30000);
// GPS STATUS
UWriteString("AT+CGPSSTATUS?\r");
// Returns: "Location Unknown"
_delay_ms(10000);
UWriteString("AT+CGPSINF=2\r");
// Returns: "2,160745,0.000000,N,0.000000,E,0,0,99.989998,187.000000,M,-187.000000,M,,0000
```

Comment: It seems you're doing everything OK. This AT commands I use on SIM908 module:
AT+CGPSPWR=1
AT+CGPSRST=0
AT+CGPSSTATUS?
AT+CGPSINF=0

and after approximately 5min. I get location 2D/3D fixed.

Comment: OK, but what does your CGPSSTATUS return when you call it in the beginning. Is it `Location Unknown` or `Location Not Fix`?

Comment: At first is Location Unknown, after couple of minutes Location Not Fix and at last Location 3D fixed.

Comment: Alright, I tried with an even longer delay. Even after 20 minutes, it still returns `Location Unknown`.

Comment: Do you have your own board or use dev. board? If it's your own board, could you please add schematic and PCB where GPS antenna is routed?

Comment: It's a custom board, but the passive antenna is connected directly to the SIM908 antenna pad.

Comment: Is the trace between antenna and SIM908 pin 50 ohm controlled?

Comment: The antenna is a 50 Ohm antenna and is connected directly, so I assume no further control is necessary. This is the antenna: http://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/1052630003_ANTENNAS.pdf

Comment: This is not GPS antenna!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried using a GPS antenna and it still wouldn't work. Sadly I have run out of time to investigate further and will have to do without the GPS.

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the width of the PCB trace and the distance between the trace going to GPS antenna to nearest reference plane(VDD or GND)?

Comment: The VBAT line has a width of 0.04in (1mm). There are large ground planes on both sides of the PCB. The GPS antenna is connected directly to the U.FL connector of the SIM908.

Answer (score 1):

To conclude, I see three possible options here:

1.) Your chip is damaged

2.) Trace between U.FL and chip is not 50 ohm controlled

3.) Your chip has been reset when trying to connect to network.

Take oscilloscope and how does the signal look on the power supply pins. You need to compensate 2A peak with bypass capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

Is your GSM engine running, and not in sleep mode, check using these commands

> AT+CFUNC? and AT+CSCLK?

Response of AT+CFUNC? must be **+CFUNC:1**, if its not gsm engine is not running then run it by **AT+CFUNC=1**

Response of AT+CSCLK? must be **+CSCLK:0**, if its not then gsm engine is in sleep(slow clock) mode to exit from sleep send command **AT+CSCLK=0**

Do a gps power cycle, then check for location.

Comment: This is quite an old question... I am sure it wasn't in sleep mode. I think I ultimately traced the problem to a bad (wrong choice of) antenna. But your comment might help others, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggle with that same problem, but finally had that solution by proceeding as follows

1. reset to factory setting by type AT&F or ATZ
2. type AT+CMGF=1
3. type AT+CGPSPWR=1
4. type AT+CGPSRST=0  delay at 5 minutes after typing this cmd.
5. finally type AT+CGPSINF=0 then you get your locations.

note: the 5 minute delay is only when, the module is just being powered ON.